# How to implement a (xmpp) listener in grails that renders a view

Tags: multithreading, session, grails, groovy, smack

I am developing a grails application and am pretty new to grails at all. Right now I got stuck in implementing a listener that needs to render a view whenever it's called (Concrete: It is a listener for incoming xmpp messages of the Smack Library). I implemented this listener in a service which works fine so far, but now I need to render a view, when the listener gets called. So I tried to access the session or the controller on many different ways from inside of the listener, but all approaches lead to this error message:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request , or processing a request outside the
>   originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a
>   web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
>   running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet. In this case
>   use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request.

In other code blocks of my service I was able to access the session, but not within my listener object:

```
def webRequest = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
webRequest.getSession()
```

Can anybody help me out here? Can I solve this using the RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter like described in the error message and if yes, how do I do that? Or is there any other way to access the controller or the session from inside my listener?

Another approach would be to implemented this listener within the controller, but will this work and will I be able to access the session this way? Or will it also be a "no thread-bound request"?

Thank you very much for your answers in advance!

Comment: if you really only need to render some html from a gsp you can utilize the ``PageRenderer`` -- see `Page Rendering API` in the docs

Comment: I tried that, using groovyPageRenderer. I get the error message displayed in the question.

Comment: a bit different approach, have you looked at `grails-events-push`, basically adding a listener in your client to react upon arrival of your xmpp message.